# How to adjust the module part of the fully-qualified class name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following test shows Python interprets `A` as `dir.a.A`. How can I make Python interprets `A` as `dir.A`?

```
$ find * -name "*.py"
dir/a.py
dir/__init__.py
main.py


$ cat dir/a.py
class A():
    pass


$ cat dir/__init__.py
from .a import A


$ cat main.py
from dir import A
print(A)


$ python3 main.py
<class 'dir.a.A'>
```

I know the following can yield the result I want, but I want to achieve it without changing the directory/file structure.

```
$ ls
dir.py main.py


$ cat dir.py
class A():
    pass


$ cat main.py
from dir import A
print(A)


$ python3 main.py
<class 'dir.A'>
```

Or, shouldn't I care about this? (I'm a newbie to Python.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. `dir.A` and `dir.a.A` are the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand *why* you want to the module part of the fully qualified class name, and why you don't want to change the file structure. That's just an information for humans. Both of your code samples seem fine to me.

Comment: Why *do* you care about this?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but try adding the line `__all__ = ['A']` in `dir/__init__.py`. ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python))

Comment: The reason I don't want to change the dir/file structure is that I'm going to create many classes and I don't want to pack them into one file (`dir.py`). Regarding the class name, if Python engineers didn't care the difference, it would be okay as an answer although in other languages `dir.A` and `dir.a.A` are different.

Comment: You shouldn't care, because you are confusing the name of the module with the Python identifier bound to the module. You could write `from dir import A as foobar`, and `print(foobar)` would still print `<class 'dir.a.A'>` Try `import os.path; print(os.path)` sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You don't need to do this, and you probably don't want to do this. The standard library is full of examples where what the documentation uses as the import location and the actual module information on the object differ:

```
>>> from unittest import TestCase
>>> TestCase
<class 'unittest.case.TestCase'>
```

The full module location is used by tools like `pickle` (to store only a reference to the class when serialising instances).

You can set the `__module__` attribute if you feel you must change it; it is a string that names the full module path:

```
>>> class A():
...     pass
...
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> A.__module__
'__main__'
>>> A.__module__ = 'dir'
>>> A
<class 'dir.A'>
```

This is the same value as the `__name__` attribute on the module. It is available as a global inside a module, in `__init__` you could use

```
from .a import A

A.__module__ = __name__  # rehome here.
```

For tools like `pickle` that's still fine because you actually *have* a `dir.A` reference in the `dir` module.

Comment: Thank you. I understood that the module part can be changed by `__module__`, and at the same time, that I don't have to do it.